# How to define Whitelist approach on Java to be able to return specific 'Type' of whitelist?

Tags: java, spring, performance, architecture, clean-architecture

I am facing a hard to decide situation(in my head)right now when I design my algorithm to filter and check whenever a things, let say CallCenter, has a allowlist for some phone number or some area and return specific type of allowlist-ing that the CallCenter applied on them. Is it allowlist for phonenumber, or for some area, or even the combination of area and phone(specific target).

Btw, in my design a CallCenter will only has one type of Allowlist ("byPhone", "byArea", or "byAreaAndPhone" )I have my approach like this:

```
//// I use call center one to many relationship to allowlist directly to get the allowlists
private void validateWhitelistOfCallCenter(CallCenter callCenter, String phoneNumber, String areaName) {
    if (callCenter.getAllowlists().isEmpty()) return;
    String typeAllowlist
    for (CallCenterAllowlist allowlist : callCenter.getAllowlists()) {
        typeAllowlist = allowlist.getType();
        if (ALLOWLIST_BY_PHONE_NUMBER.equals(allowlist.getType())
                && allowlist.getCustomerPhoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber)) return;

        if (ALLOWLIST_BY_AREA.equals(allowlist.getType())
                && allowlist.getAreaName().equals(areaName)) return;

        if (ALLOWLIST_BY_PHONE_NUMBER_AND_AREA.equals(allowlist.getType())
                && allowlist.getAreaName().equals(areaName)
                && allowlist.getCustomerPhoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber)) return;
    }
    if (ALLOWLIST_BY_PHONE_NUMBER.equals(errorType))
        throw CallCenterErrors.customerPhoneIsNotInAllowlist(phoneNumber);
    if (ALLOWLIST_BY_AREA.equals(errorType),
        throw CallCenterErrors.customerAreaIsNotInAllowlist(areaName);
    if (ALLOWLIST_BY_PHONE_NUMBER_AND_AREA.equals(errorType),
        throw CallCenterErrors.customerAreaAndPhoneIsNotInAllowlist(phoneNumber, areaName);
}
/// note: each return means the customer is in allowlist or the callcenter doesn't use any allowlist kind of things
```

Then, in my head I already feels it will be weird when the development becomes bigger let say callcenter allowlist will has more type of allowlist, then the if on the last method execution will be scaling too, and if statement inside the loop will be scaling too. Can anyone help me to decide is it good enough to do it as I make it or should I separate the validation to become one on one validation on each type of allowlist?. At first I decide not to separate the function because CallCenter Will only contain one type of allowlist, but the error return will always check the type whatever the condition of type in allowlists.

***Notes: Btw I already design a Blocklist for this kind of situation, blocklist has the opposite approach that makes it easier to apply error specification because whenever things found on loop throw error, which means the error type is same as the exact element that I found same with the specification(like byPhone or byArea).*

Comment: FYI you might want to changes the terms you are using here, Whitelist and Blacklist are in the process of being removed from many major company codebases.

Comment: @CheeseFerret owh, I am not update with current kind of things, why do they being removed now? can you help me to got the directions here

Comment: Sure thing, here's some recent links https://www.techspot.com/news/85631-github-replace-terms-whitelist-blacklist-masterslave-racially-insensitive.html https://beebom.com/google-blacklist-whitelist-removed-code/ . I hope these are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing can be fully handled by encapsulating the 'things which can be whitelisted against', and the 'whitelist type' into their own classes.

Creating an interface which represents the 'things to whitelist against' means you can pass this round to all implementations.  As long as it *has* access to all the things that *that* type needs it doesn't need to care if you add more details to it later:

```java
public interface WhitelistContext {
    AreaName getAreaName();
    PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber();
}
```

You can then have your `WhitelistType` be *another* interface which accepts one of these `WhitelistContext`s.

```java
public interface WhitelistType {
    public void validate(WhitelistContext context) throws ValidationException;
}
```

Then have each `WhitelistType` class be in charge of it's own validation:

```java
public class AreaWhitelistType implements WhitelistType {
    @Override
    public void validate(final WhitelistContext context) {
        AreaName area = context.getAreaName();
        // Do whatever else you need here...
    }
}
```

That way, if you add more elements to the `WhitelistContext` it won't impact any of the existing `WhitelistType`s, you don't need an ever-growing list of arguments to your method, and instead of having an `if (...) else` block covering all the types, you can just loop through, passing the `WhitelistContext` to each one and letting *it* worry about that.

For dealing with the different `CallCenter`s, you can either add this to the `WhitelistType` interface as an argument, so that it can get details from there, or have the constructor for the implementations of that class take one and know how to use it.  Either way would be fine IMHO.

Comment: hmm, interesting but I hope `WhitelistType` is an enum, I use string above because I don't know is enum the right answer or not. I use enum also to be able to translate by JPA to stored on db as String

Comment: `enum`s can implement `interface`s so there's nothing stopping you there.  Although that does stop you being able to pass the `CallCenter` in the constructor and means it would have to be another parameter on the `validate` method.

Comment: I need more real example of code implementation from my example of code implementation